# Extract value to points runs but table won't open

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, point

I am running ArcMap 10.4.

I have a point file and a raster and I am trying to run extract values to points. It runs successfully, but when I go to open the table I get this error:

> Error reading OID from table. Reading rows has been stopped. Check
> that the datasource is valid.

I have done this in the past with no issues, I even tried it on a raster/point file that I have done the exact operation with before and get the same error. So I don't really think it's an issue with the data itself (although I'm sure it's possible).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check by creating a new file geodatabase and creating a copy of feature classes
2. Check if you have any M value enabled on feature class,
   [remove M/Z values](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010389) and retry
3. If you are using a File geodatabase run the Check and repair geometry tool and retry your workflow. [Check and Repair Geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/checking-and-repairing-geometries.htm)